# boost::serialization of one instance per unique ID

Tags: c++, serialization, boost-serialization

I'm trying to boost::serialize structures which point to objects (say, of symbol class) implementing an idea of a single-instance-per-unique-<something>. That means, those objects are not created directly, but using a static method symbol::get(). This method retrieves an existing object from some global dictionary or creates a new object if necessary.

Now the hard part is that in my system I have many large structures with pointers to such symbols. The structures don't fit all in the memory at the same time. So I need to sequentially build, preprocess and serialize each of the structures separately. Later I'll deserialize and process structures on request.

Standard boost::serialize methods, namely load(...) and save(...) don't work here. Uppon deserialization of a structure would lost the system-wide uniqueness of symbols and serialization would waste a lot of space (my symbol objects are quite large). I've read the boost docs and found that for nonstandard constructors I can use save_construct_data and load_construct_data functions. But docs say also, the default load_construct_data "just uses the default constructor to initialize previously allocated memory". So again this isn't it.

The question is: how can I bypass this loading function so I can avoid any allocation and use my symbol::get() instead? Or maybe there is a more elegant solution?

EDIT: attached a simple code demonstrating the problem.

```
struct structure_element {
};

class symbol : public structure_element {
  symbol(string x);
  map<string, symbol> known_symbols;
public:
  static symbol *get(string x) {
    if (known_symbols.find(x) != known.symbols.end()){
      known_symbols[x] = symbol(x);
    }
    return &known_symbols[x];
  }
}

class structure_node : public structure_element {
  set<symbol *> some_attributes;
  vector<structure_element *> children;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the exceptional cases can *implement* **[`load_construct_data`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#constructors)** (obviously this implies you *don't* rely on the default implementation as you already observed in your question).

More specifically: use Boost Flyweight. Or look at how they [implemented serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/flyweight/serialize.hpp) for inspiration.

<strike>Without a concrete sample program I'm unable to demonstrate things for you.</strike>

Filling in some of the blanks, here's a demo program that should give a feel for things:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/set.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>

#if 0
#   define DEMO_FLYWEIGHT
#   include <boost/flyweight/serialize.hpp>
#   include <boost/flyweight.hpp>
#endif

struct structure_element { 
    virtual ~structure_element() {}

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& /*ar*/, unsigned /*version*/) {
    }
};

namespace detail {
    struct symbol_impl {
        symbol_impl(std::string const& x) : _x(x) { }

#ifdef DEMO_FLYWEIGHT
        size_t hash() const { return boost::hash_value(_x); }
        //bool operator< (symbol_impl const& other) const { return _x <  other._x; }
        bool operator==(symbol_impl const& other) const { return _x == other._x; }
#endif

      private:
        std::string _x;

        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned /*version*/) {
            ar & _x;
        }
    };
}

#ifdef DEMO_FLYWEIGHT
namespace boost {
    template <> struct hash<::detail::symbol_impl> {
        size_t operator()(::detail::symbol_impl const& s) const { return s.hash(); }
    };
}
#endif

struct symbol : public structure_element {
    symbol(std::string const& x) : _impl(x) {}

  private:
#ifdef DEMO_FLYWEIGHT
    boost::flyweight<detail::symbol_impl> _impl;
#else
    detail::symbol_impl _impl;
#endif

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned /*version*/) {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<structure_element>(*this);
        ar & _impl;
    }
};

struct structure_node : public structure_element {
    structure_node(std::set<symbol*> a, std::vector<structure_element*> c) 
        : some_attributes(std::move(a)), children(std::move(c))
    {
    }

    // TODO value semantics/ownership
  private:
    std::set<symbol *> some_attributes;
    std::vector<structure_element *> children;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned /*version*/) {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<structure_element>(*this);
        ar & some_attributes;
        ar & children;
    }
};

#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

int main() {
    // everything is leaked, by design
    symbol* bar = new symbol("bar");

    structure_node data { 
        {
            new symbol("foo"),
            bar,
            new symbol("foo"),
            new symbol("foo"),
            bar,
        },
        { 
            bar,
        }
    };

    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
    oa << data;
}
```

Notes:

- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5aeb9b713e26b051)</kbd>** ***without*** flyweight

  ```
  22 serialization::archive 11 0 0 1 0
  0 0 0 4 0 3 1 0
  1
  2 0 0 3 bar 3
  3
  4 3 foo 3
  5
  6 3 foo 3
  7
  8 3 foo 0 0 1 0 3 1
  ```
- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c3023429ac3b6d0)</kbd>** ***with*** flyweight enabled

  ```
  22 serialization::archive 11 0 0 1 0
  0 0 0 4 0 3 1 0
  1
  2 0 0 0 0 0 3 bar 3
  3
  4 1 3 foo 3
  5
  6 1 3
  7
  8 1 0 0 1 0 3 1
  ```

Note how objects are already tracked when serializing through pointer. This implies that no duplicates are serialized even when not using flyweight, see e.g. the `bar` object being used 3 times.

For the `foo` object, you can see that it's implementation is "deduplicated" if you will when using flyweight.

> Boost Flyweight is highly configurable and can be made to perform significantly better than the default. I refer to the library documentation if you want to learn more

Comment: I've attached a sample. Thanks for pointing the 'flyweight', I didn't know this pattern name. Brief look at the boost::flyweight shows, that it is more or less the thing I need, but I have to somehow put flyweight<symbol> into my class hierarchy (I didn't mention this aspect previously, sorry). I would like to hear your detailed comment.

Comment: @bzaborow and you have it